# Guardar en .TXT el resultado de un Stored Procedure a partir de la ejecución de un JOB

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

1.-Para ejecutar un Stored Procedure se hace de la siguiente forma:
exec sp_dias 'parametros';

2.-Para imprimir una cadena de texto en un archivo es asi:
echo este es un fichero>E:archivo.txt

3.-Mi duda es si, es posible mandar el resultado de la ejecución del Stored Procedure desde el Command del JOB
es decir:
exec sp_dias ''>E:\archivo.txt;
Sin embargo la sintaxis anterior es incorrecta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
En el siguiente Stored Procedure, supuestamente debe generar el TXT desde el SP a apartir de que se ejecuta desde
el JOB;sin embargo no he tenido éxito y ahora quiero hacerlo usando el punto 3, lo cual evitaría usar BCP y demas permisos como:
-c -T EXEC, master..xp_cmdshell etc, ademas de que la consulta sería más estetica o normal por asi decirlo.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[consulta_diariaFinal] 
@Hoy DATETIME
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT @Hoy = GETDATE()
DECLARE @comando VARCHAR(2000)
DECLARE @query VARCHAR(2000)


SET @query   ='bcp "SELECT c.CodeCompany,'+@Hoy+' AS fechaActual,a.idClave,c.nombre +'' ''+c.apellidos AS Nombre,d.Descripcion AS Depto,t.HorasAlDia AS HorasDia, convert(char(8), fechaEntrada, 108) as Entrada,convert(char(8), fechaSalida, 108) as Salida,DATEDIFF(HOUR,fechaEntrada,fechaSalida) % 24 AS horasAlDia FROM tblasistencia a JOIN tblpersonal c ON a.idClave=c.idClave JOIN tblTurno t ON t.idTurno=c.fkTurno JOIN tblDepto d ON c.fkDepto=d.idDepto WHERE fechaEntrada BETWEEN '+@Hoy+' AND DATEADD(DAY,1,'+@Hoy+') and fkStatus !=1" queryout E:\archivo.txt -c -T'
SET @comando = @query + ' -Usa -P123456'

EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @query
END
```

Comment: ¿Porbaste usar el outfile? Algo asi como
`SELECT * INTO OUTFILE "C:\sql.txt" FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' FROM tabla;`

Comment: Por curiosidad hermano, ¿Lograste solucionarlo?

Comment: @Sacha lo voy a intentar hacer y comento los resultados

Comment: @fredyfx Si lo solucione pero no use Stored Procedure 
1.Con una pàgina web en PHP. 
2.-Realice las respectivas consultas en la página web
3.-Guarde la consulta en un txt con PHP
4.- Ejecute la página web desde una bat con una tarea programada de Windows

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque la pregunta fue solucionada cambiando la tecnología y aplicando otras técnicas mencionadas en los comentarios que están fuera de las etiquetas de la pregunta original.

Comment: me alegra saberlo :D en ese caso, vamos a cerrar la pregunta para mantener el orden en el sitio, un abrazo :D